# Registration for different roles

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I have 3 roles, which I want registered on my site:

- client
- partner
- trainer

All roles must have different fields in the registration form.
Now I have form for registration only clients.
I think, generating 3 different forms is a true way for solution this problem.
How can I create 3 forms, one for each role?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: As stated, your question is very broad.  Could you post any code you've tried?

Comment: Use scenarios for different roles